# cant connect with sqlsrv_connect() to ms sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am trying to connect to my database by IP using this code:

```
$serverName = "195.181.245.55,49163\BCPLIUS2017";
$connectionInfo = array(
'Database' => 'dbname', 
'UID' => 'dbuser', 
'PWD' => 'dbpass');
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if($conn){
 echo "Database connection established.<br />";
}else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

I can connect without any problems with HeidiSQL client using exact data that I use in my php script.

With php connection I get this error

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 10013
>   [code] => 10013 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP
>   Provider: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by
>   its access permissions. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for
>   SQL Server]TCP Provider: An attempt was made to access a socket in a
>   way forbidden by its access permissions. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => HYT00
>   [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired [message] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired ) [2]
>   => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 10013 [code] => 10013 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A
>   network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
>   Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online. ) )

What I am doing wrong?

I'am sure that server allow remote connections

Comment: Can you try with `server\instance,port` or `server,port` format - `$serverName = "195.181.245.55\BCPLIUS2017,49163"` or `$serverName = "195.181.245.55,49163";`?

Comment: Try without port and instance name, leave only IP. I had the same issue on one setup when I removed it, it started to work.

Comment: all your suggestions failed :(

Comment: Try disabling your firewall.